# Get data attribute value and output image equal to this value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to this, I'm looking to get the data-rating value of each line of HTML and output the same image a multiple amount of times for each line, dependent on each value, using jQuery/Javascript.

Here's a sample of the HTML:

```
<div class="review-value" data-rating="5"></div>
<div class="review-value" data-rating="7"></div>
```

How can I best do this?

Comment: use `.attr("data-rating")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way to do it.

- Get the attribute for each div.
- Run the loop that many times and add an image in each iteration

```js
$('.review-value').each(function() {
  for (var i = 0, len = parseInt($(this).attr("data-rating")); i < len; i++) {
    $('<img src="#" />').appendTo($(this))
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="review-value" data-rating="5"></div>
<div class="review-value" data-rating="7"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$('.review-value').each(function (index, value) { 
  alert('div' + index + ':' + $(this).attr("data-rating")); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Data` is HTML's attribute. you can use that as well with Jquery `each` loop and store the value in `Array`

```js
var getRating = [];
$('.review-value').each(function () { 
  getRating.push($(this).data("rating")); 
});

alert(getRating);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="review-value" data-rating="5"></div>
<div class="review-value" data-rating="7"></div>
```

Comment: You are missing `$` is here `getRating.push($(this).attr("data-rating")); `

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) that can help you get the value of any data attributes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".review-value").each(function() {
    console.log('Rating: ' + $(this).data('rating'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="review-value" data-rating="5"></div>
<div class="review-value" data-rating="7"></div>
```